# Привязка навигатора к фреймам в двух окнах

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Имеется окно с объектом Frame и навигатор привязанный к Frame

```
Navigator.Service = Frame.NavigationService;
```

По одной из кнопок в контенте объекта Frame, открывается  доп окно ExtWindow с объектом ExtFrame (тип Frame).

```
ExtensiveWindowCommand = new RelayCommand(p =>
        {
            ExtWindow = new ExtensiveWindow();
            ExtWindow.Show();
            ExtWindow.Activate();
            ExtWindow.ExtFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(new DataView(), this);
        }, o=>(ExtWindow==null || !ExtWindow.IsVisible));
```

Доп окно содержит область отображения данных основного окна вместе кнопками навигации.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: как сделать так чтоб кнопки навигации работали и там и тут, не переписывая команды навигации (DataContext окон привязаны и одному объекту ViewModel)?

Строчка

```
Navigator.Service = ExtWindow.ExtFrame.NavigationService;
```

перекидывает навигатор на доп окно, после чего в основном навигация перестает работать.

Comment: Можно конечно повесить на окна события Activated и по его срабатыванию перекидывать навигатор, но это уже костыли

Comment: Проблему решил путем применения вкладок вместо отдельной навигации

Comment: Для читателей вопроса было бы полезно знать, а что такое вообще `Navigator`. Я, например, не в курсе. Это из какой-то библиотеки?